# summing values in an async function from listeners in android studios

Tags: java, android-studio

im trying to use an API (baincace) to get an amount of available coins. this is my code.

++++++EDIT++++++

this all function is in a request form firebase, i added the code before my last publish. see that we iterate over a map for each "user" to get his name then sum up his assets.

```
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, ctCredentials>> gType = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,  ctCredentials>>() {};
                HashMap<String, ctCredentials> map = task.getResult().getValue(gType);
                map.forEach((clientName, credentials) ->{
                    BinanceApiClientFactory factory = BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance(credentials.getKey(), credentials.getSecret());
                    BinanceApiAsyncRestClient client = factory.newAsyncRestClient();
                    client.getAccount(new BinanceApiCallback<Account>() {
                        double sum = 0;
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Account account) {
                            for(AssetBalance ass : account.getBalances()){
                                String coin = ass.getAsset();
                                if(currencies.contains(coin)){
                                    cAmounts.put(coin,ass.getFree());
                                }
                            }
                            client.getAllPrices(new BinanceApiCallback<List<TickerPrice>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(List<TickerPrice> tickerPrices) {
                                    text_preveiw.add(clientName);
                                    text_preveiw.add("Total Free in USDT: ");
                                    sum+= Double.parseDouble(cAmounts.get("USDT"));
                                    for(TickerPrice tp : tickerPrices){
                                        String symbol = tp.getSymbol();
                                        if(symbol.contains("USDT")){
                                            String cName = symbol.replaceAll("USDT","");
                                            if(currencies.contains(cName)) {
                                                double price = Double.parseDouble(tp.getPrice());
                                                double amount = Double.parseDouble(cAmounts.get(cName));
                                                sum += (price * amount);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    text_preveiw.add(Double.toString(sum));
                                    text_preveiw.add("\n");
                                    StringBuilder ptxt = new StringBuilder();
                                    text_preveiw.forEach((t) ->{ptxt.append(t).append("\n");});
                                    preview.setText(ptxt);
                                }
```

notice there are two onResponse functions because i want to make sure they happen in the order i want them to execute. there is a double named sum in the begining of the Oncreate function , so i reset the value on each iteration. but for some reason the values are the same or they dont make sense. i tried using synchronized on the Sum object but it didnt work. im having trouble summing the values maybe because the functions fire asynclly? thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you show how you define `sum`, where are use it, and what behavior you are seeing?

Comment: @TylerV hi, lets say that the answer is 61 for the first iteration, them sometime the value could be more (the value is actually from the second iteration) or duplicates of values

Comment: You should try making it a class variable instead of local